# PSModule provider is missing

Tags: windows, laptop, powershell, windows-10-preview, windows-packagemanagement

I recently installed Windows 10 on my laptop. Problem is that I cannot install apps from `OneGet` because I cannot install `Chocolatey` source because `PSModule` provider is missing. Screenshot:

[[image: provider is missing]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kz2P.png)

I also screenshoted my main PC where everything works fine:
[[image: Everything is fine pic]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1DXj.png)

how can it be fixed?
Difference between PC: I have MSVS2015 installed on main PC, and it was updated from 8.1 against laptop clean install

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, OneGet is in flux. The initial version of OneGet shipped
>   with Chocolatey as its sole default repository, but Chocolatey has now
>   been removed from the default configuration. A Chocolatey package
>   source will soon be available for easy installation via OneGet. You
>   can currently install the Chocolatey package source with a command,
>   but Chocolatey’s packages wouldn’t actually install on our system
>   after doing so. This is a minor roadbump in development.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/200334/windows-10-includes-a-linux-style-package-manager-named-oneget/?PageSpeed=noscript